# Получить следующий селект, после заданного

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер,дан селект, как получить следующий селект, после заданного селекта, если неизвестен id селекта?
Мне нужно в зависимости от выбора первого селекта активировать второй селект.
Вот я попробовала, на основе комментария и ответа, не получается...

```html
 <script>
    function SetFilter(id){
        alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
        if (document.getElementById(id).value!='-')
          $("#"+id).nextAll("div select:first").attr('disabled','');
        else
          $("#"+id).nextAll("div select:first").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    </script>
    <div>
        <p class="flabel">Марка</p>
        <select name="PROPERTY_CML2_MARKKA" id="PROPERTY_CML2_MARKKA" onchange="SetFilter(id)">
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="audi">audi</option>
            <option value="audi2">audi2</option>
            <option value="ford">ford</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="flabel">Модель</p>
        <select name="PROPERTY_CML2_MODEL" id="PROPERTY_CML2_MODEL" onchange="SetFilter(id)">
            <option value="-">-</option><option value="audi 5">audi 5</option>
            <option value="ford model1">ford model1</option>
            <option value="model2">model2</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="flabel">Год выпуска</p>
        <select name="PROPERTY_CML2_YEAR" id="PROPERTY_CML2_YEAR" onchange="SetFilter(id)">
            <option value="-">-</option>
            <option value="1999">1999</option>
            <option value="2006">2006</option>
        </select>   
    </div>
```

Что-то не хватает? Мне необходимо следущий селект сделать активным/неактивным

Comment: @Jean-Claude, обновила html код

Comment: @Jean-Claude, все равно не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну а если так:

**Javascript:**

```
function SetFilter(id){
    // Текущий селект
    var el = $('#' + id);
    // Идентификатор следующиего нужного селекта
    var next = el.attr('data-next-item');

    if (next) {
        if (el.val() !== '-') {
            $("#" + next).removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $("#" + next).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <p class="flabel">Марка</p>
    <select data-next-item="PROPERTY_CML2_MODEL" id="PROPERTY_CML2_MARKKA" onChange="SetFilter(id)">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="audi">audi</option>
        <option value="audi2">audi2</option>
        <option value="ford">ford</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="flabel">Модель</p>
    <select data-next-item="PROPERTY_CML2_YEAR" id="PROPERTY_CML2_MODEL" disabled onchange="SetFilter(id)">
        <option value="-">-</option><option value="audi 5">audi 5</option>
        <option value="ford model1">ford model1</option>
        <option value="model2">model2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="flabel">Год выпуска</p>
    <select id="PROPERTY_CML2_YEAR" disabled onchange="SetFilter(id)">
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="1999">1999</option>
        <option value="2006">2006</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Суть: указываешь у селекта, каким будет следующий, и обрабатываешь.

**Живой пример:**

http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/yOXGqv

Comment: `data-next-item`- атрибут, который вы придумали? Не думала , что атрибуты можно придумывать....

Comment: можно =) Но не совсем просто, все атрибуты должны начинаться с `data-`. Вот доки http://htmlbook.ru/samouchitel-html5/atributy-data

Comment: можно и заменить атрибут `data-next-item` на `name`,- все работает. Спасибо за бесценные знания!

Comment: все можно, просто для хранения мета-данных лучше использовать атрибуты свои. Атрибут `name` все же зарезервированный, и логика его это - имя текущего элемента, а не следующего. У всего должна быть своя логика)

Answer (score 2):

Зависит, конечно, от DOM-структуры.

Вот несколько рецептов:

1. Если элементы следуют строго друг за другом, используйте `next(селект)`.
2. Если они следуют друг за другом, но разделены другими неоднотипными элементами, то попробуйте `nextAll(селект:first)` - покажет первый найденный элемент. Если же нужен какой-то НЕпервый, то можно вот так: `$(nextAll(селект)->get(номер))`.
3. Можно так же использовать [sibling-селекторы](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).

P.S. Писал по памяти без проверки, подпилите под себя.

Comment: попробовала по-вашему, не получается-(((